# Use pattern to bind data frames in R with .csv data frames in folder

Tags: r

I know there are couple ways of binding files in folder into one big data frame (like `rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\.\\d+")))` from `data.table` package). This is not what I intent to do here. I need to bind data frames I have in my R environment with data frames in  folder with .csv files. R dfs and .csv dfs have same structure (similar enough for `rbind.fill`).

Data frame names have indicators which are first 4 character. So in R data framse looks like this: `DF01`,`DF02`,`DF03`. In folder .csv are noted like this: `DF01_a`,`DF01_B`; `DF02_a`,`DF02_b`;`DF03_a`,`DF03_b`.

So as you can see for each data frame in R I will have multiple .csv to add so I figured out easiest way is to bind them using pattern. For example `pattern=substr(df.list,1,4)` which should bind dfs based on first 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
DF01 = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(3,2,1))
DF02 = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(3,2,1))

my_dfs = ls()[grepl('DF',ls())]

library(data.table)
for (i in 1:length(my_dfs))
{
  thisdf <- get(my_dfs[i])
  files_to_add <- list.files()[grepl(my_dfs[i],list.files())]
  dfs_to_add <- lapply(files_to_add,fread)
  dfs_to_add[[length(dfs_to_add)+1]]= thisdf
  assign(my_dfs[i],rbindlist(dfs_to_add,fill=T))
}
```

I have three files called `DF01_a.csv`, `DF01_b.csv` and `DF02_a.csv` in my directory, output:

```
> DF01
   a b
1: 4 6
2: 5 7
3: 4 6
4: 5 7
5: 1 3
6: 2 2
7: 3 1

> DF02
   a b
1: 4 6
2: 5 7
3: 1 3
4: 2 2
5: 3 1
```

Hope this helps!